# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.Worker" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, dex, androidx, aar

I have been trying to make an android library, whenin I'm making use of WorkManager's PeriodicWorkRequest. It works flawlessly as a module in the host development app. However, once I export it as an aar file and use it in another app, I get the following error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/Worker;
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.Worker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testapp-0WusKIYjC1qsHRMASLjm1Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.testapp-0WusKIYjC1qsHRMASLjm1Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AAR by itself does **not** embed or otherwise encode anything about the transitive dependencies (such as your AAR's dependency on WorkManager), so it is expected that if you're just using an AAR as a [local binary dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-types) that you'd need to redeclare all of the transitive dependencies.

As per the [Gradle Declaring Dependencies documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html), a proper dependency is in the form of a maven repository (either local or remote). A maven repository, besides hosting the AAR itself, also includes a [POM file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) that declares the transitive dependencies your library depends on. This ensures that there's only one version of each library included in your build (as it can deduplicate transitive dependencies across multiple libraries).

You don't see this same issue when locally using a project since those transitive dependencies are included as part of the build process.

Comment: This worked. However, I find it weird that I have to redeclare all the AAR dependencies in the app gradle again. Can't gradle just pick up the transitive dependencies?

Comment: An AAR by itself doesn't have any concept of dependencies - it is just a jar, resources, and a manifest. That's why every respectable library isn't published just as an AAR you download into a local directory, but as a Maven dependency which does have a concept of transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you have a dependency error , the app your are trying to use your library use **androidx support library** , try to change `WorkManager's`  dependency to `androidx` dependency

Comment: I have already added androidx dependency for WorkManager. Refer @ianhanniballake's answer, it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: great then you fixed your problem

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the inputs anyway.

Comment: your are welcome , you can upvote it if it was helpful , maybe it can help other person here